# How to set a fixed screen size in flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to test my flutter app on a real device (no emulator) but would like to set a smaller screen size.

As this is just for development how the app looks on smaller devices, the space around can just be empty.

I tried wrapping the Scaffold or the MaterialApp in a Container, SizedBox, ... with fixed sizes but it always takes up the whole screen.

Comment: Change the font size in your device and it will just work for your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [device_preview](https://pub.dev/packages/device_preview) plugin - you will be able to simulate the app running on different devices' types even when launching on your physical device.

Just remember not to release the app with this plugin implemented.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for but it seems I used the wrong search terms.